# Accessing a server-side VLAN through OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, kubernetes, kube-openvpn

I am a networking noob and could use some help.

I am trying to set up a TAP connection using OpenVPN to access devices that are on a VLAN on my remote server.  Right now, I can connect and ping the interface (172.20.0.101), but I can't ping anything on the VLAN (like 172.20.0.2).  I don't care about the VLAN coming accross my VPN connection, I just want to be able to see those devices.

The "public" IP for the server is 10.249.2.93 (this is actually a LAN I connect to over another VPN).

The subnet I want to be able to talk to is 172.20.0.0/24, which is on vlan.3072, according to ifconifg.  The associated physical interface is enp3s0.

I had this working on a different server that does not use a VLAN, i.e. I was able to successfully connect to devices on a regular LAN behind that server, so I think the VLAN is the issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Any help is very much appreciated, as I am going losing my mind =P

Server is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, OpenVPN 2.4.4

Client is running Windows, OpenVPN GUI 11.14.0.0

server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
server-bridge 172.20.0.101 255.255.255.0 172.20.0.200 172.20.0.240
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 4
explicit-exit-notify 1
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
dh dh.pem
user nobody
group nogroup
cert server.crt
key server.key
```

clinet.ovpn:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote 10.249.2.93 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
script-security 2
verb 4
# cert and keys omitted
```

ufw rules:

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules

#change:
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

forwarding:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

#change:    
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo sysctl -p
```

rules updates:

```
sudo ufw allow 1194/udp
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

bridge-start script:

```
# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="enp3s0"
eth_ip="fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="172.20.0.255"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br inet6 add fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3/64 up
ifconfig br0:0 172.20.0.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 172.20.0.255 up
```

ifconfig (not showing the br0 or tap0 because I can't start them right this minute, and also there are a ton of other veth* I omitted):

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:60ff:fe8c:45de  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:60:8c:45:de  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 74394  bytes 900967774 (900.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63778  bytes 901066960 (901.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.249.2.93  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.249.15.255
        inet6 fe80::c600:adff:fe94:e303  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c4:00:ad:94:e3:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 960832  bytes 1168467699 (1.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 166  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 535763  bytes 73093159 (73.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xb2500000-b2520000

enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:5a:11:33:e8:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:5a:11:33:e6:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9900475  bytes 7053325760 (7.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10464489  bytes 8238594873 (8.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

kube-bridge: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1480
        inet 10.244.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.244.0.255
        inet6 fe80::841:c2ff:fed1:3642  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:41:c2:d1:36:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2110720  bytes 234803960 (234.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2264621  bytes 419964189 (419.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8383864  bytes 4038115926 (4.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8383864  bytes 4038115926 (4.0 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth83317517: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1480
        inet6 fe80::d4c3:65ff:fe76:7592  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:c3:65:76:75:92  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28251  bytes 7794531 (7.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29314  bytes 3608931 (3.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vlan.2560: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.128.0  broadcast 172.19.127.255
        inet6 fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:5a:11:33:e6:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70170  bytes 25019840 (25.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 179  bytes 17252 (17.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vlan.2816: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.130.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast      172.19.130.255
        inet6 fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:5a:11:33:e6:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1243206  bytes 65936318 (65.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1194999  bytes 99652577 (99.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vlan.3072: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.20.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:5a:11:33:e6:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8544935  bytes 6820405811 (6.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 511  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9265376  bytes 8138226312 (8.1 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

except from ip a:

```
7: vlan.3072@enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:5a:11:33:e6:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.100/24 brd 172.20.0.255 scope global vlan.3072
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a5a:11ff:fe33:e6e3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bridge configuration in `bridge-start` makes a bridge between `tap` and `enp3s0`, so any frames coming from the client end up on `enp3s0` without any vlan tags. That's why it was working without VLANs, and that's why it doesn't work with them.
You should bridge between `tap` and `vlan.3072` on a server side for your setup to work, so just change `enp3s0` to `vlan.3072` in your `bridge-start` script.